# Как в MySQL в поле типа SET исключить вложенные совпадения средствами БД?

Tags: mysql, типы-данных

Добрый день!

Есть таблица в БД вида:

**id**          integer(11)
**time**        time
**weekday**     set('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')
**capacity**    time
**comment**     varchar(100)

UNIQUE (time, weekday)

Туда пишутся данные вида *"07:30:00; mon, tue, wed, thu, fri; 00:30:00; 'текст'"*

Можно ли средствами БД проверять есть ли вложенные совпадения в столбце 'weekday'?
Например:
*"07:30:00; mon, tue, wed, thu, fri; 00:30:00; 'текст'"

"07:30:00; sat, sun; 00:30:00; 'текст'"*

можно, а:
*07:30:00; mon, tue, wed, thu, fri; 00:30:00; 'текст'

07:30:00; fri, sat, sun; 00:30:00; 'текст'*

уже нельзя?

Comment: А тут нет никаких совпадений. Записи уникальны. А если Вы о том, что в обеих записях установлен бит `fri` - ну так это последствия денормализации, сиречь кривая структура. И штатными средствами контроля целостности и непротиворечивости данных сервера MySQL добиться подобной "уникальности" не удастся.

Comment: Т.е. мне либо делать столбцы на каждый день недели, либо перед добавлением проверять совпадения в коде?

Comment: Вам - изменить схему данных, чтобы она была нормализована... фтопку SET().